# how to write code for onitemClickListener for customized listview using BaseAdapter?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, custom-adapter

here is the code for custom listview using BaseAdapter in android its working fine:

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private ArrayList<TaskClass> _listData;
    Context _c;

    public CustomListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<TaskClass> listData) {

        _listData = listData;
        _c = context;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return _listData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return _listData.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position,View convertView,ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) 
        {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflator = (LayoutInflater) _c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = layoutInflator.inflate(R.layout.listview_row, null);
        }
        TextView titleText = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.holdTitleText);
        TextView  catText = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.holdCatText);
        TextView  descText = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.holdDescText);
        TextView  dateText = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.holdDateText);
        //CheckBox checkBoxForEachItem = (CheckBox)v.findViewById(R.id.)
        TaskClass taskClassInstance = _listData.get(position);
        titleText.setText(taskClassInstance.getTitle());
        catText.setText(taskClassInstance.getTaskCategory());
        descText.setText(taskClassInstance.getDescription());
        dateText.setText(taskClassInstance.getTaskDate());
        return v;


    }


}
```

and in activity i m binding listview with custom adapter :

```
listViewInstance.setAdapter(new CustomListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),taskClasslistInstance));
```

where "taskclasslistinstance" is my arraylist conatining data from DB its working fine
now i need to write function for listitemclick so that when user click on any listitem i can get **rowid**  of that listitem record from **Database**.so after getting rowwid I can delete records from listview and from db and can  edit informations

Comment: ask google instead of stackoverflow? You are looking for the "long id", or you can set an manual "id" view setTag() in getView and get it  in the clicklistener via v.getTag

Answer (score 1):

Well, we don't know about your `TaskClass`, but I expect you want something like this:

```
listViewInstance.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
        TaskClass taskClass = taskClasslistInstance.get(pos);
        Log.d(TAG, "Clicked on: " + taskClass)
        // Do stuff with taskClass
    }});
```

Comment: yes your code is working fine but i m getting data of takclass i need row id from database how can i get this? as my task class has no attribute of ID  may i need to add id attribute in my task class i m beginner and getting difficulty to implement this

Comment: Yes, I would recommend yout taskclass holds an `id` field and it is the row id from the database. You can populate it when you get the data from your database and build your `TaskClass` list. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: i m trying to put data in database directly to the function and that fuction exists in my adapter class i m not using taskclass instance and its set method to set values in database so in this scenerio how can i get row id if i put id attribute in my taskclass then how to get values?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Maybe if you post some DB code in a new question? Currently there is no DB code anywhere for me to look at so it's quite hard to advise.

Comment: how can i add notepad file in SO? i m sending you code of my database and taskclass

Comment: how can i add notepad file in SO? i m sending you code of my database and taskclass

Comment: I think, based on the information you have provided, I have provided the best answer I can. If you have another question please post it to Stack Overflow with all the necessary information and someone will answer it for you. Good luck!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32203/discussion-between-user1668447-and-ken-wolf)

Comment: here is the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17249330/what-is-the-best-approach-to-save-values-in-databaseusing-android-and-sqlite                                                                   if u can answer me then i would be more thankful to u

Answer (score 0):

Here a small example from my project:

```
 list = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);

    adapter = new LazyAdapterAlbum(getActivity(), songs);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), AlbumActivity.class);
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putString(AlbumActivity.ALBUM_NAME, adapter.getItem(position).getName());
            i.putExtras(args);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

You have to set an onClickListener on your ListView.

Answer (score 0):

you can also set in getView method like below:

```
public View getView(int position,View convertView,ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) 
        {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflator = (LayoutInflater) _c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = layoutInflator.inflate(R.layout.listview_row, null);
        }
        TextView titleText = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.holdTitleText);
        TextView  catText = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.holdCatText);
        TextView  descText = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.holdDescText);
        TextView  dateText = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.holdDateText);
        //CheckBox checkBoxForEachItem = (CheckBox)v.findViewById(R.id.)
        TaskClass taskClassInstance = _listData.get(position);
        titleText.setText(taskClassInstance.getTitle());
        catText.setText(taskClassInstance.getTaskCategory());
        descText.setText(taskClassInstance.getDescription());
        dateText.setText(taskClassInstance.getTaskDate());

       v.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Perform an action when this list item is clicked
        }
    });
        return v;


    }
```